Integral divergence implies summation divergence
Assume $f:(0,1)\times (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a nonnegative continiuos bivariate function such that
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f^2(x,y) dx dy = \infty,\quad \int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) dx dy = 1.$$
Can we conclude that
$$\lim_{m\to \infty} m^2 \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^m \left(\int_{\frac{i-1}{m}}^{\frac{i}{m}} \int_{\frac{j-1}{m}}^\frac{j}{m} f(x,y) dx dy\right)^2 = \infty?$$
Intuitively, if for $m$ large enough, we assume $f$ is roughly $f(\frac{i}{m},\frac{j}{m})$ on each small square, then the left hand side of the above expression is
$$m^2 \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^m \left(\frac{1}{m^2} f(\frac{i}{m},\frac{j}{m})\right)^2 = \frac{1}{m^2}  \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^m f^2(\frac{i}{m},\frac{j}{m}) $$
which should be an approximation of integral $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f^2(x,y) dx dy $.
But I don't know how to prove it rigorously or find a counter example if it is wrong. Any hints are appreciated.
Update: I just noticed that
$$m^2 \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^m \left(\frac{1}{m^2} f(\frac{i}{m},\frac{j}{m})\right)^2 \geq \frac{1}{m^2} \sum_{i,j} \inf_{\frac{i-1}{m} < x < \frac{i}{m},\frac{j-1}{m}<y<\frac{j}{m}} f^2(x,y)$$. Can the condition imply the right hand side diverge?
